# Static blocks in transactionals email for multilingual stores

Tags: static-block, transactional-mail, email-translation

we have got a multilingual stores which has been translated into Polish, Italian, French and German. We used several static blocks e.g. to display our general business terms and I succeeded in including this content in the different languages for the different store views. The identifier of the different blocks is the same for the different languages.

Now I would like to translate also Magento's transactional emails. In some of the mails, we also use static blocks, e.g. to display our general business terms.

I would like to know, how this has to be managed. If the identifier is the same for all languages, how is it possibile to display e.g. the Italian general business terms in the Italian transactional emails? Or do I have to change the identifier? Can the identifier be the same of different languages / different store views?

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is the following

Copy your transactional mail templates for each store view and then add the specific block into each of them as follows:

Create a new email template in `System > Transactional emails` then assign this new template at store view level in `System > Configuration > Sales Emails` and for example for "New Order Confirmation Template"

Then in these add you specific static blocks for each store view